# Android: Inflater not working inside custom view. How to write something to text view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have created a custom view. Here is the layout of my custom view.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.lenze.android.poc_arcdraw.ArcView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The name of above file is sample_arc_view.xml. My view file is

```
public class ArcView extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView mTextView;
    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        readParametersFromAttributeSet(context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcView));
        init(context);
    }
       private void init(Context context) {

       View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_arc_view,this); // stuck here
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView); // this line is never executed

    }
}
```

Now, whenever I am executing this code it always gets stuck in inflater. I am not able to reach to next line and program crashes. Logs are not helpful as there is no error or exception. [Here](https://shrib.com/RxrLCt6a2YESah7) is the link for logs.

I want to write some dynamic text in the text view.

Comment: what happens if you run it (without the debugger)?

Comment: replace your line with this `LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_arc_view,null);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this also. This also doesn't work.

Comment: running without debugger also doesn't help. App opens and crashes

Answer (score 1):

You entering an endless recursion of inflates. Once you try to inflate 
sample_arc_view.xml, android inflater will call constructor of you ArcView.
Wich will try to inflate same layout in endless recursion call.

Comment: Yes, Nikolay's response is correct. I am going in endless recursion. Also, I am not getting stack overflow error which is strange. What could be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. Nikolay's answer helped me in finding error. It was stackoverflow indeed but was never thrown. I am not sure why. I modified my code a little. 
New XML is like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

I removed the line : com.lenze.android.poc_arcdraw.ArcView so recursive calls to ArcView constructor are removed.
I also modified code for inflator to:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View mCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_arc_view, this,true);
```